# C++ обьяснить участок кода

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Описан класс. Не понимаю двух моментов:

1. Зачем приводить к типу `void*`, когда пользуешься `memcpy`
2. У методов после их названия, для чего стоит `const`?

Код привожу ниже:

```js
class CDataArray {
private:
 int* pData;
 int NumEl;
public:
 CDataArray(int* pArray, int n) {
  NumEl = n;
  pData = new int[n];
  memcpy((void*)pData, (void*)pArray, 4 * NumEl);
 };
 CDataArray() {
  NumEl = 0;
  pData = NULL;
 };
 CDataArray(int n) {
  pData = new int[n];
  NumEl = n;
 };
 ~CDataArray() {
  if (NumEl > 0) delete[] pData;
 };
 int Size() const {
  return NumEl;
 }
 int* GetPtr() const {
  return pData;
 }
};
```

Comment: К void можно и не приводить, но по привычке можно :) почему в memcpy void тип? - по причине что он работает с любыми указателями на объект и использует параметр размера обьекта, этой информации достаточно для копирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Зачем приводить к типу void*, когда пользуешься memcpy

Незачем. Ошибкой это не является, просто бессмысленная операция.

> У методов после их названия, для чего стоит const?

Таким образом объявляется метод, вызов которого не меняет состояния экземпляра класса. Такой метод не может изменять состояния полей, за исключением данных, объявленных с ключевым словом `mutable`, а также не может вызывать неконстантные методы этого же класса.

В целом класс написан плоховато, стиль на троечку. Не то, что стоит изучать в качестве примера.